# How can you use getSObjectValue() in a child component who's property is declared with @api?

Tags: lightning-web-components, parent-to-child

**Summary:**

Is there a way to pass an object from a parent component to a child component so that the child component can use `getSObjectValue()` to read field values?

The naïve implementation fails because the child component's property is declared as `@api`, which exposes a Proxy object that is incompatible with `getSObjectValue()`.

**Details:**

When reading values from an object returned from an Apex call, the Salesforce recommendation is to import the appropriate fields from the schema and to use `getSObjectValue()` to read the field values.

This is documented here:

[Import Objects and Fields from @salesforce/schema](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_schema)

However, if you pass an object from a parent component to a child component using the exposed `@api` property, then you can no longer use `getSObjectValue()` in the child component because `@api` exposes a Proxy object, which `getSObjectValue()` cannot handle.

Is there a way to pass an object to a child component and still be able to use `getSObjectValue()` to read the appropriate field value? If not, is there another way to import the fields from a schema into a child component so that dependency tracking is still performed?

Consider the following parent-child example where the parent component wants to render a bunch of child component elements for each `Contact` returned from an Apex call:

**Parent Component:**

The parent component [calls an Apex method imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative) to fetch a list of all `Contacts`:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllContacts from '@salesforce/apex/getAllContacts';

export default class ContactsBrowser extends LightningElement {
  @track contacts;
  @track error;

  handleLoad() {
    getContactList()
     .then(result => {
       this.contacts = result;
     })
     .catch(error => {
       this.error = error;
     });
  }
}
```

**Parent Template:**

The parent template then renders each contact in a child component, passing in the appropriate `Contact` through the child's `@api` property:

```html
<template>
  <template lwc:if={contacts}>
    <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
      <c-contact-row key={contact.Id} contact={contact}></c-contact-row>
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
```

**Child Component:**

The child component exposes `@api contact` and uses `getSObjectValue()` to read a field value from the given object. However, this will fail because `getSObjectValue()` expects a normal JavaScript object but `contact` is actually a `Proxy` object.

Using `contact.Name` works fine, but then we're no longer taking advantage of the imported field and potentially losing some dependency tracking.

```js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { getSObjectValue } from '@salesforce/apex';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';

export default class ContactRow extends LightningElement {
  @api contact;

  get name() {
    // This fails because `contact` is a Proxy object.
    return getSObjectValue(this.contact, NAME_FIELD);
  }
}
```

**Edits:**

*In an attempt to create a simple example, the initial version of this post used the `@wire` service instead of calling an Apex method imperatively, like the real code does. This mistake results in very different answers. Apologies for the confusion.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said [a few times before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=proxy+user%3A2984+%5Blightning-web-components%5D), `Proxy` is almost certainly not the problem here. `Proxy` is nearly perfectly transparent to code running live, it just so happens that `console.log` outputs the `Proxy` instead of its `[[Target]]`, which is what the `Proxy` is trapping.

It's more likely that you're running into specific conditions because you're using a getter. Depending on the circumstances, the LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) may not realize that you've changed the value, and therefore skips checking the getters. It is far more reliable in this case to set the value from the `@api` property itself:

```
name;
#contact; // # denotes private variable
@api set contact(value) {
  this.name = getSObjectValue(value, NAME_FIELD);
  this.#contact = value;
}
get contact() {
  return this.#contact;
}
```

Doing this should improve the reactivity of the variable, but note that you need to make sure that you don't try to modify `this.#contact`, as it is still read-only unless/until you copy it. If you never need to get the value, you may omit the getter.

Comment: Thanks for the input and answers to previous questions. There's some good information in them on the `Proxy` object. This `get/set` pattern seemed to be overkill to me but I guess that's how it's done. I noticed that Salesforce uses this pattern in some of their [LWC-Recipes sample code](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes-oss/blob/main/src/modules/recipe/todoList/todoList.js). My component is read-only and nothing more than a reusable "card" for showing field values of a given record. Read only properties seemed more idiomatic, but perhaps problematic.